# Organized R Package Manual Help Pages (Table of Contents)

Tags: r, package, markdown, roxygen2, manual

Maybe I'm just not searching for the right things but hoping someone can help me here in terms of package development.  I'm wondering how to get the overall help page of my R package to contain alphabetized links/subsections to all of the functions in package instead of one giant list.

My current R package manual page (when I click on page name in RStudio looks similar to many and just as an example here is DESeq2 page:
[image]

Then there are packages whose pages look like this, again just as example here is dplyr page:
[image]

I'm guessing this has something to do with a section or header when building the package with roxygen2 but couldn't seem to find answer to my question from searching.

Thanks!
Sam

Comment: Those files are automatically generated. The alphabetical index will only appear if you have more than 100 items in your help page (ref: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/80a7ca3b605b34d207ed3465c942f39a37e89f6e/src/library/tools/R/install.R#L2770)

Comment: Got it, thanks so much!  No way to force override of that it seems :/.  Thanks again!